# How to create extra root user?

Tags: linux, permissions, bash, user-management, users

I have tried making a root2 user which should have the same permissions as root by doing

```
useradd -g root root2
passwd root2
usermod -G root root2
usermod -aG wheel root2
```

but root2 can still not cat /etc/shadow as an example.

How can I create such user?

Comment: There can only be one root user. You can use `sudo` to give administrative privileges to other users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. `root` is a special user with uid 0. Use `sudo` instead.

Comment: Interesting! With my above commands `root2` have a GID of 0, how come that doesn't give the user full root privileges?

Comment: because a GID is not a UID.

Comment: So what does it give `root2` to have GID of 0?

Comment: Nothing that would give it real root permissions (aka is allowed to do everything). You can access files that are group-accessible for group `root`, but that's about it.

Comment: You can in fact have multiple root users. Just use a text editor to change root2 uid to 0. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/48/tag/16.html

Comment: @dmourati: Yes, I know this but this will be essentially the same user, because the user id is the same and you might end up with some hard-to-understand side effects. Using `sudo` is simple and effective.

Comment: @sven I agree with you above

Answer (score 11):

*Premise: using `sudo` (as suggested by the accepted answer) probably is the correct solution at your problem.*

That said, if you *really* need something resembling a second `root` account, you can create an *alias* to the system `root` account.

To do that, follow these steps:

1. open `/etc/passwd`
2. locate the `root` account line (often the very first line). It will be something similar to `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`
3. copy/paste it changing the first `root` occurence in `root2` (ie: changing it in `root2:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`)
4. save your changes and exit the text editor
5. issue `passwd root2` and enter the new password

Note: if you whish, you can avoid direct editing the `/etc/passwd` file by replacing steps 1-3 with the following command: `useradd -o -u 0 -g 0 -N -d /root/ -M root2` (see `useradd --help` for more information about the required options)

At this point, you can login using not only the original `root` account (with its original password), but also using the new `root2` account (with its *new* password).

Anyway, remember that it is an alias of an existing user, rather than a completely new user. This means that any files created while logged as `root2` have the very same numerical oid/gid of the original system `root` account (which has `0` as both uid and gid).

Answer (score 4):

This used to be somewhat common (before `sudo` alleviated the need).

The [toor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toor_(Unix)) user (yes, that's "root" spelled backwards) is the most common alternate root user, sharing the special UID of zero with root.  See also this Super User question: [Does the root account always have UID/GID 0?](https://superuser.com/questions/626843/does-the-root-account-always-have-uid-gid-0)

This is the purpose of `useradd --non-unique` (`useradd -o`).  I believe you want something like:

```
useradd --non-unique --uid 0 root2
```

You should be able to give the account any that doesn't already exist on your system.

I do not recommend this.  You're far better off with one true root user, reserved for emergency console access.  Admins should all instead use sudo.  Especially remote admins (it is wise to prohibit root from connecting via ssh or other remote services, especially w.r.t. password logins).

Answer (score 0):

Install sudo:

```
# apt install sudo
```

Create user and set password:

```
# useradd myuser
# passwd myuser
Enter new UNIX password: 123
Retype new UNIX password: 123
```

Add user to sudo config:

```
# visudo
...
myuser    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Login as myuser and get root permissions:

```
# su myuser
$ sudo apt install vim
[sudo] password for myuser: 123
...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib vim
  vim-runtime
```

I think you need to read some information about [permissions](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/these-key-elements-of-access-permissions-are-everything-to-your-linux-server-security.html) and [user management](http://ccm.net/contents/328-linux-user-management) in linux.